# Get element attribute value

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract a form element value using regexp:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("name=\"(token)\"[^>]*value=\"([^\"]+)\"", 2);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(result); 

if(matcher.find())
{
    String value = matcher.group(2);
}
```

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="YToxOntzOjU"/>
```

However, my `matcher` yields no results. What am I missing?

Comment: How can you tell that it has no result?

Comment: [This](http://regex101.com/r/oI7zI3) shows your regex as working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not [**parse HTML using regular expressions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), but your written code seems to work fine?

```
String result  = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"token\" value=\"YToxOntzOjU\"/>";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("name=\"(token)\"[^>]*value=\"([^\"]+)\"", 2);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(result); 

if (matcher.find()) {
   String value = matcher.group(2);
   System.out.println(value); //=> "YToxOntzOjU"
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://ideone.com/qDmeBZ)

Comment: @Johan Escaped quotes are needed in String _literals_. Where does that value come from?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yeah, I misread it a bit. It's a response from a HttpClient -> InputStream -> to string. Perhaps I'm better off with a parsing library for html nodes?

Comment: @johan Yes, most probably. But the code you provided works for this case. You must not have what you are showing us.

Comment: @Johan Yes indeed, use a parser instead of trying to use regular expressions.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well, I've posted what I get when stepping through the code using a breakpoint. Perhaps the debugger translates   html entities e.g. `<` is actually something like `&lt;`? However, I think I'll go find a parsing lib instead. Got any suggestions?

Comment: @Johan jsoup probably.